# Why are the coefficients in a multinomial logistic regression a matrix?

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn, regularization, multinomial-logit

I am conducting an analysis in which I have 3 different groups and a set of 80 continuous variables that I think can discriminate between the 3 groups. I want to:

1. see if indeed I can discriminate the groups with these variables, and
2. get an idea of which of these variables are the most effective in discriminate between the two groups.

To this aim, I have decided to conduct a multinomial linear regression with *l1* penalty as implemented in scikit-learn. After having fitted the model with my data, I found that indeed the 3 groups can be discriminated and the *l1* penalty worked as expected: the solution is sparse as most of the coefficients are set to 0. However, I do not understand the output of the model: when I look at the coefficients of the model, what I got is an array with the dimensions: *number of groups x number of variables*. This seems to mean that the coefficients are calculated for each group, but this does not make much sense. This is the type of output that I would have expected using a *one-vs-rest* approach to multiclass logistic regression, not using a multinomial one.

How should interpret the output of my model?

Comment: Consider how matrix multiplication is defined, and then review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_set_of_independent_binary_regressions

Comment: @Sycorax: Thanks for the hint. I think I get  it now, at least from a mathematical viewpoint). Still, I am having an hard time to conceptually interpret the output. If I had a binary dependent variable, I could look at my coefficients and say that those variables whose coefficient has not been zeroed are the most discriminative. Having three sets of coefficients (each set with different non-zeroed variables) which conclusion can I draw ?